# Multivariable: How can I show the limit does not exist?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

How can I show the limit does not exist?

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{xy^2}{(x^2+y^4)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} $$

I'd rather not using polar representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x=y$, then you get
$$
\frac{x^3}{(x^2+x^4)x} \sim 1
$$
as $x \to 0$. But if you approach the origin along the two coordinate axes...

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Take $x = my$ and evaluate the limit.